# How do I combine HAVING and GROUP BY in the same SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by

My current query is as follows:

```
SELECT user_id, sum(...) as total from mytable
group by user_id
```

Which works fine

However when I try

```
SELECT user_id, sum(...) as total from mytable
group by user_id
having total >= 10
```

I get an error

```
SELECT user_id, sum(...) as total from mytable
having total >= 10
```

Works fine.  How can I combine HAVING and GROUP BY?

Comment: What error do you get? Running all three queries works for me, I just get different result sets.

Comment: `@deltanovember:` which database do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id, sum(...) as total from mytable
group by user_id
having SUM(...) >= 10
```

Comment: `@BoltClock:` It dependce on the Database. mysql also takes `total` in having, mssql not.

Answer (score 0):

HAVING is used together with aggregate functions, not columns. It's like the where clause, but for aggregates.